# Execute if status is changed wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, api, bots, chatbot

I'm using `motors` theme. I have a viber bot and want to send a message if status of selected car is changed to `is-exist`.

status variable:

```
$status = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'status', true );
$status = urldecode($status);
```

code that should be executed if status is changed to is-exist:

```
$client->sendMessage(
    ( new \Viber\Api\Message\Text() )
        ->setSender( $botSender )
        ->setReceiver( $receiverId )
        ->setText( 'New Renault Megane with status "Is exist") );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `update_postmeta` hook to check whenever a post-meta changed. Here is what the hook looks like (taken from `meta.php`):

```php
/**
 * Fires immediately before updating a post's metadata.
 *
 * @since 2.9.0
 *
 * @param int    $meta_id    ID of metadata entry to update.
 * @param int    $object_id  Post ID.
 * @param string $meta_key   Metadata key.
 * @param mixed  $meta_value Metadata value. This will be a PHP-serialized string representation of the value
 *                           if the value is an array, an object, or itself a PHP-serialized string.
 */
do_action( 'update_postmeta', $meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
```

So something like this:

```php
add_action('update_postmeta', function($meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value) {
  if( $meta_key === 'status' && $meta_value === 'is-exist' {
    //... send notification
  }
}, 10, 4);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer. Sorry that my delayed reply. I should make this for brand Renault. brand is `make` in DB. Why didn't you used status like this:
`
 `$status = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'status', true );
$status = urldecode($status);
if ($status==='on-road')`
???